# how to respond/send multiple objects from controller to view in grails?

Tags: grails, grails3

We have not been able to find an example of how to do this anywhere.

It seems the way to send data from a controller to a view is using respond.  Usually respond takes one argument. We want to send many.

E.g. if we have a control panel, with many different datas being displayed (users account balances, recent transactions, messages etc).

Our controller looks like this:

```
def index() {

    User user = User.find (session.getAttribute("user"))
    def accounts = Accounts.findAllByUser(user)
    def messages = Messages.findAllByUser(user)

    // this doesn't work, but we guess something like this might be possible.
    respond [accounts:accounts, messages:messages]
}
```

Additionally, findAllBy documentation doesn't say what it returns. It might be an array, a map, a list.

Then in our views we should be able to do something like:

```
${accounts[0].balance}
```

or maybe

```
${accounts.size()}
```

if findBy... returns a list.

Comment: you can just return a map, take off the respond from your example above so it becomes `[accounts:accounts, messages:messages]`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Mike W, the answer is:

```
def index() {

    User user = User.find (session.getAttribute("user"))
    def accounts = Accounts.findAllByUser(user)
    def messages = Messages.findAllByUser(user)

    [accounts:accounts, messages:messages]
}
```

Its a shame this is not in the examples in the docs, its a very useful feature